# Differences between JSON & Python syntax

Tags: python, json

I have a request log from a server JSON REST API. I want to be able to turn this into a python script to replay that sequence of events.

Ideally i'd like the content to be easy to modify. So it would be perfect if I could actually translate the JSON into python Dictionaries/lists. i.e. From -

```
{"BoolVal":true, "SomeList":["a","b","c"]}
```

to

```
data = {"BoolVal":True, "SomeList":["a","b","c"]}
```

Are there any differences other than the true/false True/False that i'd need to be aware of?

*I need to do this on the server which does not have python. i.e. I want my users to be able to download a script to replay their actions.

Comment: To translate between Python structures and JSON, use the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Yes: quotes (JSON uses `"` while python allows either single or double `'`' / `"`, string escaping etc. Do not attempt to write your own parser using `string.replace()`, just import the json module and use `load()` or `loads()`.

Comment: I'm not doing this in python. I'm generating a python script on a server running C#.

Comment: And you can't put a json string in the script?

Comment: That is what I currently have. But ideally i'd like to format it into valid code. This is designed as a tool to help people writing scripts against the API. i.e. I want to offer the ability to perform a list of actions using the UI. Then from the logs generate a script which only needs minor modification to be useable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `json` then it will be like string

```
a = '''{"BoolVal":true, "SomeList":["a","b","c"]}'''
```

You can convert it using `json` module.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(a)
{u'SomeList': [u'a', u'b', u'c'], u'BoolVal': True}
```

`json.loads` will return you valid python object.

Comment: I need to do this in non-python code. So can't use json.loads.

Comment: C#. I want to generate a valid python script on the server from a request log which can be downloaded and run by users.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your JSON is a string, e.g. `'{"BoolVal":true, "SomeList":["a","b","c"]}'`.

You can load it into a python data structure using the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads(json_string)
>>> print d
{u'SomeList': [u'a', u'b', u'c'], u'BoolVal': True}
```

Comment: I need to do this in non-python code. So can't use json.loads.

Comment: @user2036256 You need to run it in a python script. With no python? I think you need to clarify your question because this makes no sense.

Comment: I want to generate a valid python script which a user can download from the server. Its designed as a tool to help users automate tasks using the API. I.e. you run actions against the UI then can download a script which can repeat them.